# Job fails with Unable to load resource hudson/tasks/junit/Messages.properties

Tags: jenkins, hudson

A couple of our jobs were failing with:

> java.lang.Error: Unable to load resource hudson/tasks/junit/Messages.properties

Searching the net revealed that incorrect permissions on /tmp could cause this, but it was not the issue in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with .ssh directory missing on the slave machine (ssh master/slave setup).